# Pandas: Set Value Of Column To Value of Index Based On Condtion

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping this is a simple question.... I simply want to keep track of the last time a condition was met in a data frame. My plan was to first add a row which will take the value of the index when a condition is met. I then planned to use fillna to fill the extra rows so each row has the last time the condition was met. However I can't seem to find any way to set the value of a new column to the value of the index based on a condition without getting incorrect data or an error. Below is an example with the desired result but I get `ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape`?

```
rows = 50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows,2), columns=list('AB'), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=rows, freq='1H'))

df.loc[df.A > 0.5, 'LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df.index
# ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape

df['LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df['LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Desired result:

```
print df.tail()

                            A         B LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X
2000-01-02 19:00:00  0.952454  0.046514 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 20:00:00 -0.216546 -0.254344 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 21:00:00 -0.237128 -0.830337 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 22:00:00  0.889550  0.060698 2000-01-02 22:00:00
2000-01-02 23:00:00  0.172436 -0.566921 2000-01-02 22:00:00
2000-01-03 00:00:00  1.092696  1.053605 2000-01-03 00:00:00
2000-01-03 01:00:00  1.284858  0.117552 2000-01-03 01:00:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mask the rhs also so change `df.loc[df.A > 0.5, 'LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df.index`  to `df.loc[df.A > 0.5, 'LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df.loc[df.A > 0.5].index`:

```
In [175]:

rows = 50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows,2), columns=list('AB'), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=rows, freq='1H'))

df.loc[df.A > 0.5, 'LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df.loc[df.A > 0.5].index
# ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape

df['LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df['LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'].fillna(method='ffill')
df
Out[175]:
                                                A  \
2000-01-01 00:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 01:00:00 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   
2000-01-01 02:00:00 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   
2000-01-01 03:00:00 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999   
2000-01-01 04:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 05:00:00 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   
2000-01-01 06:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 07:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 08:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 09:00:00 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999   
2000-01-01 10:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 11:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 12:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   
2000-01-01 13:00:00 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999   
2000-01-01 14:00:00 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999   
2000-01-01 15:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00   

                                                B LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X  
2000-01-01 00:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00                 NaT  
2000-01-01 01:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 01:00:00  
2000-01-01 02:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 02:00:00  
2000-01-01 03:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 02:00:00  
2000-01-01 04:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 02:00:00  
2000-01-01 05:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 06:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 07:00:00 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 08:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 09:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 10:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 11:00:00           1970-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-01 05:00:00  
2000-01-01 12:00:00 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001 2000-01-01 05:00:00
```

The above produces an error, this has something to do with the fact it's a datetimeindex and assigning the values is being broadcast on the whole df which is wrong, if you reset the index and perform the same masking and then set the index back you get the desired output:

```
In [192]:

rows = 50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows,2), columns=list('AB'), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=rows, freq='1H'))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
temp = df.loc[df.A > 0.5,'index']
df.loc[df.A > 0.5, 'LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = temp
df['LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df['LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'].fillna(method='ffill')
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df
Out[192]:
                            A         B LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X
index                                                      
2000-01-01 00:00:00 -1.015624  1.156609                 NaT
2000-01-01 01:00:00 -1.223371 -1.378067                 NaT
2000-01-01 02:00:00  1.012627 -0.324465 2000-01-01 02:00:00
2000-01-01 03:00:00  1.298507 -1.216586 2000-01-01 03:00:00
2000-01-01 04:00:00  0.985638  0.058768 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 05:00:00 -0.815905  0.586401 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 06:00:00 -1.185344  2.177858 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 07:00:00 -0.638001  0.046314 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 08:00:00 -0.134608  0.294528 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 09:00:00  0.425651  0.709888 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 10:00:00 -0.378901 -0.877367 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 11:00:00 -0.504592  0.322824 2000-01-01 04:00:00
2000-01-01 12:00:00  1.442753 -1.145960 2000-01-01 12:00:00
2000-01-01 13:00:00  0.437722 -0.445725 2000-01-01 12:00:00
2000-01-01 14:00:00  2.509730 -0.106108 2000-01-01 14:00:00
2000-01-01 15:00:00 -0.618179 -1.079270 2000-01-01 14:00:00
2000-01-01 16:00:00 -1.377722 -1.445645 2000-01-01 14:00:00
2000-01-01 17:00:00  0.529527 -2.500947 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-01 18:00:00 -0.263954 -0.576484 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-01 19:00:00 -0.177062  0.422974 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-01 20:00:00  0.173764  2.116644 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-01 21:00:00 -1.248605 -0.594601 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-01 22:00:00 -1.138183 -0.282523 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-01 23:00:00  0.047580  0.496086 2000-01-01 17:00:00
2000-01-02 00:00:00  1.618901 -1.910404 2000-01-02 00:00:00
2000-01-02 01:00:00  0.127997  0.783554 2000-01-02 00:00:00
2000-01-02 02:00:00  0.702277  1.720010 2000-01-02 02:00:00
2000-01-02 03:00:00 -0.801874 -2.302547 2000-01-02 02:00:00
2000-01-02 04:00:00  1.636838 -0.940251 2000-01-02 04:00:00
2000-01-02 05:00:00 -1.204564  0.517969 2000-01-02 04:00:00
2000-01-02 06:00:00 -0.700013  0.075867 2000-01-02 04:00:00
2000-01-02 07:00:00 -0.234283 -1.899428 2000-01-02 04:00:00
2000-01-02 08:00:00  0.730711  0.254155 2000-01-02 08:00:00
2000-01-02 09:00:00 -0.188994  2.035390 2000-01-02 08:00:00
2000-01-02 10:00:00  1.384640 -1.319800 2000-01-02 10:00:00
2000-01-02 11:00:00 -0.288324 -1.219386 2000-01-02 10:00:00
2000-01-02 12:00:00 -0.642150 -0.449078 2000-01-02 10:00:00
2000-01-02 13:00:00  1.615771  0.497375 2000-01-02 13:00:00
2000-01-02 14:00:00 -1.422133  1.934081 2000-01-02 13:00:00
2000-01-02 15:00:00 -1.541841  1.202525 2000-01-02 13:00:00
2000-01-02 16:00:00 -2.463243  0.020996 2000-01-02 13:00:00
2000-01-02 17:00:00 -0.445203  0.462241 2000-01-02 13:00:00
2000-01-02 18:00:00  0.376458 -1.190448 2000-01-02 13:00:00
2000-01-02 19:00:00  1.040431  0.006403 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 20:00:00 -0.145096 -0.961192 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 21:00:00 -0.127414  0.604989 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 22:00:00 -0.054637  0.070836 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-02 23:00:00 -0.581572  0.634429 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-03 00:00:00  0.021646  0.837573 2000-01-02 19:00:00
2000-01-03 01:00:00 -1.785810  2.178076 2000-01-02 19:00:00
```

**EDIT**
After posting this on the [pandas github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9478) site the conclusion is that this is a bug and that for this to work the safe method is to perform the following:

```
df.loc[df.A > 0.5,'LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X'] = df.loc[df.A > 0.5].index.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum for the fast reply. It seems to have the desired effect on the new column `LAST_TIME_A_ABOVE_X` but it has also modified the data in columns `A` and `B` to now be time fields and lost the original data? As shown in your results

Comment: I think this is a bug, after looking at this, it should not be doing this, let me investigate

Comment: @PH82 it looks like a bug if you set the values to an index where the index is a datetimeindex, if you reset the index, perform the masking and assignment and set the index back then it works fine

Comment: Okay thanks @EdChum. For completeness could you give me an example of how to modify my code to reset the index? Should the bug be reported?

Comment: @PH82 my edited answer includes the code for reseting the index and setting it again, yes it should be reported at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues), you should add a reference to this SO post and code to reproduce the error which is the upper half of my answer, you can reduce the number of rows to 5 or 10 to reproduce the error

Comment: Perfect, thanks. For completeness here is the suggested solution from github `df['TIME_ABOVE_ZERO'] = df.index.to_series().where(df.A>0.5)`